# SharePoint 2013- Add custom web application/page which uses files from other folders

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, createjs

I've created a JavaScript web browser game. The HTML page, `Game.html`, within folder `Game` references several other JS/jQuery/CSS files stored in sub folders.

I simply want to add the `Game` folder, which includes the `Game.html` file and all of its related files to SharePoint 2013 as a page. That way people can play the game on SP 2013.

[image]

I've tried the following:

- Clicked `Add Page`. This gives me the Master Page and only allows me to add web parts. So I tried adding a Content Editor Web Part and tried to reference the `Game.html` page, but then I can't reference the rest of the needed JavaScript.
- Then I mapped my drive directly to the server and uploaded my `Game` folder to the server. From there, I created a Master Page of `Game.html` in Design Manager... this did not work.

Is there a simple way to add my `Game.html` page to SP 2013 and have it reference all of its required JS files and actually run the game?

Thanks

---

**Edit**: Okay, here's what I did:

1) I uploaded all assets to `http://server/SiteAssets/Forms/AllItems.aspx`, including main `Game.html` file, and supporting images and JS files.

2) Changed all references in `Game.html` to match the same folder that Game is in:

```
    <script src="http://Server/SiteAssets/createjs.js"></script>
    <script src="http://Server/SiteAssets/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="http://Server/SiteAssets/jquery.js"></script>
etc...
```

3) Went to `Settings -> Add a page`, which is now at `http://Server/Pages/Game.aspx`.

4) Added Content Editor Web Part (CEWP) to new Page, titled `Game`. Edited the CEWP to get the `Game.html` file located in `SiteAssets`.

5) `Game.html` seems to render okay:

[image]

However, when I submit my name in the text box, it's supposed to run the JavaScript game. But it's not working. I know it's running JavaScript because I did:

Game.html: `<body onload="test()">`

Game.html: `function test() { alert("working"); }` Outputs *"working".*

There's no console output error. And the jQuery and rest of the code seems to render for a second, flicker, and then return to the static HTML...

- So initially the HTML text field and button from `Game.html` are loaded:
  [image]
- When I type my name in and press enter... it calls `init()`, and loads jquery/createJS,etc
  [image]
- But then a second later all that disappears and only shows static HTML from `Game.html`
  [image]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

We've had all sorts of issues with running our own apps within Sharepoint pages.

In the end we went for an entirely different approach. We simply set the app up as an independent site on the same server and then included it into the sharepoint page as a web part. (Essentially an iframe).

It's definitely worth checking out as it entirely removes the associated headaches of sharepoint intercepting requests and the like.